# remove shared drive from left bar

Tags: macos

How can I remove a "shared" drive from the left bar of MAC OS x mavericks?
I've tried all the suggestions I can find online, but nothing seems to work.  It is a drive called "psce8cef", and I do not know when I first saw it.

Thanks,

## --Mike

Answer (score 1):

Open Finder Preferences, under the tab sidebar you can uncheck what all files or folders youdon't want to be displayed.[image]